# PHPExcel export

Tags: php, export-to-excel

i have table:

```
No. | Hari  | Tanggal | Masuk   | Keluar |  Durasi terlambat |  Durasi Lembur Pagi |    Durasi |  Lembur Sore | Keterangan<br>
1   | Thursday |    01/10/2015 | 00:00 | 00:00 | 00:00  
2   Friday  02/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
3   Saturday    03/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
4   Sunday  04/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
5   Monday  05/10/2015  07:26   19:35   00:00   00:13   03:05   
6   Tuesday 06/10/2015  07:22   17:56   00:00   00:17   01:26   
7   Wednesday   07/10/2015  07:31   01:00   00:00   00:08   00:00   
8   Thursday    08/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
9   Friday  09/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
10  Saturday    10/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
11  Sunday  11/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
12  Monday  12/10/2015  07:28   18:48   00:00   00:11   02:18   
13  Tuesday 13/10/2015  07:23   20:00   00:00   00:16   03:30   
14  Wednesday   14/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   Tahun Baru Islam 1437
15  Wednesday   14/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   Tahun Baru Islam 1437 H
16  Thursday    15/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
17  Friday  16/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
18  Saturday    17/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
19  Sunday  18/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
20  Monday  19/10/2015  07:25   16:52   00:00   00:14   00:22   
21  Tuesday 20/10/2015  07:28   17:04   00:00   00:11   00:34   
22  Wednesday   21/10/2015  07:31   18:11   00:00   00:08   01:41   
23  Thursday    22/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
24  Friday  23/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
25  Saturday    24/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
26  Sunday  25/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
27  Monday  26/10/2015  07:25   18:48   00:00   00:14   02:18   
28  Tuesday 27/10/2015  07:19   18:53   00:00   00:20   02:23   
29  Wednesday   28/10/2015  07:25   16:42   00:00   00:14   00:12   
30  Thursday    29/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
31  Friday  30/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   
32  Saturday    31/10/2015          00:00   00:00   00:00   <br>
```

i dont have idea to export to excel please help me

Comment: Datas are from database table ?

Comment: Assuming that this is a database table: if you only need a simple csv file, then use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function; if you want a real BIFF-format (xls) or OfficeOpenXML-format (xlsx) file, then use a library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/) - [How to export data to an excel file using PHPExcel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611148/how-to-export-data-to-an-excel-file-using-phpexcel)