# PHP Export Data to Excel

Tags: php, export-to-excel

Need help!
I'm just new in php and dont know how to export a data from database to excel.

The excel format must be like this:
[image]

Can you help me or suggest a function where this format can be make?
The Headers like Hit Rate,Production Time, Service Time will be hard coded.
The YC Alabang,and all the records under the headers will be coming from database.
Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be Excel or is csv ok?

Comment: It must be a excel file sir

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHPExcel library. With this library, you can compose the excel file with any complex of header structure.

[PHPExcel Library](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Also please check this article on Stackoverflow

[How to export data to an excel file using PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611148/how-to-export-data-to-an-excel-file-using-phpexcel)

This link will give you better look on coding style.

Comment: udated link for above library is https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel  which is archieved and it's successors link is https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [EasyXLS Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com). The pic shows me that you need to export an Excel file from database, with the cell from headers merged, borders and gray background.

This link shows you how to export data from database to Excel in PHP. It has a special section on this matter only:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-to-excel-in-php-asp.html

This link shows how to set the borders and cell background:  http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/format-excel-cells.html
like

```
$xlsStyleHeader->setBackground((int)$COLOR_GRAY);
$xlsStyleHeader->setBorderColors ((int)$COLOR_GRAY, (int)$COLOR_GRAY, 
                                  (int)$COLOR_GRAY, (int)$COLOR_GRAY);
$xlsStyleHeader->setBorderStyles ($BORDER_BORDER_MEDIUM, $BORDER_BORDER_MEDIUM, 
                                  $BORDER_BORDER_MEDIUM, $BORDER_BORDER_MEDIUM);
```

This links shows you how to merge the cells:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/excel-merge-cells.html
like

```
$xlsTable = $workbook->easy_getSheet("Sheet1")->easy_getExcelTable();
$xlsTable->easy_mergeCells_2("A1:C3");
```